# docker postgres Изменение образа

Tags: postgresql, docker

Хочу взять обычный образ postgres с docker hub и добавить в него пользователя (это все что нужно для корректной работы).

1) Забираю образ и запускаю : `docker run -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:11.5`.

2) Подключаюсь к серверу `postgres` с помощью клиента и добавляю пользователя.

3) Комичу свой образ и пушу на свой аккаунт в `docker hub`

4) Забираю образ с тестовой машины

В итоге пользователя нет...почему? оно так вообще работает (нашел такое в инете, вроде писапли что рабочая фишка.

пожалуйста направьте что и куда копать

Comment: Самой БД в образе нет, она создается в момент первого старта контейнера. Посмотрите раздел "Initialization scripts" в описании образа https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres И в своем образе положите нужный файл инициалзации в стартовый каталог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контейнере `postgres` из Docker Hub предусмотрели это, добавив возможность указать имя нового пользователя, а также его пароль и название его БД. Эти параметры передаются через переменные среды при запуске:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -e POSTGRES_DB=docker library/postgres
```

Или в DockerFile:

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER docker
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD docker
ENV POSTGRES_DB docker
```

Ответ взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26599273/9690114)